# control the visibility of user's records to other mangers

Tags: role-hierarchy

I would like to control the visibility of user's records to other mangers.

Example, Lead and opportunity records should be visible only to the user's manager. and should not be visible to all managers.

As per the attached image,
[image]
the lead and opportunity records who created by UserA1 and UserA2 should be visible to his reporting manager "Manager A" but those records should not be visible to "manager B"

your Ideas Please!! Thanks in Advance ..

Note: 
Lead and opportunity both are in private with "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" option enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57699/discussion-between-rao-and-sab-dev).

Comment: Can anyone help me on this please :(